# How to keep persistent SQL Proxy Unix Socket with Google Compute Engine

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql, unix-socket

I have a GCE instance that uses older mysql connection type and in order to connect to a Google Cloud SQL instance, I open an SSH connection through the browser on the GCE instance and run the following:

```
> cd /
> ./cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/cloudsql -instances=my-gce-instance-name:us-east1:my-sql-instance-name &./cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/cloudsql -
```

And then it is open for connections.  The problem is, when I close the browser window (or even sign into Google with a different user), the connection is lost.  Is there any way to persistently run this Unix socket with Google Cloud Engine?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can run a command in the background by appending a `&` to the end of the command. This will start a background process for the proxy. You can stop  the proxy with `killall cloud_sql_proxy`.

Another solution would be to run the proxy as a service. How to do this wildly varies by distro and version. Ubuntu 16 is typically bundled with [systemd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/systemd.1.html).